# React Typescript Argument of type 'TFunctionDetailedResult<object>' is not assignable to parameter of type react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next, react-i18next

I have this code snippet in many places of my project. This worked without any issue until I upgrade all my packages including `react-scripts` `typescript` and `react-i18next`.

```
import _get from 'lodash/get';
const { translate } = useLocales();

  translate(
          _get(error, 'response.data.validationFailures.0.field')  ,
          _get(error, 'response.data.validationFailures.0.code') 
        ),
```

The error that I am getting is

> Argument of type 'TFunctionDetailedResult' is not assignable
> to parameter of type 'SnackbarMessage'.

Making `_get(error, 'response.data.validationFailures.0.field') as String` won't solve the problem either.

But I have a similar problem before,

```
.required(translate('validations.organization.name', 'Organization name is required.'))
```

Here I got this error message

> Argument of type 'DefaultTFuncReturn' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'Message<{}> | undefined'.

I have solved the error by adding this file to the project

**i18next.d.ts**

```
import 'i18next';

declare module 'i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    returnNull: false;
    
  }
}
```

The issue was `validations.organization.name` would return `null`. So after overriding that this is not returning `null`, the issue was fixed.  Hope if I declare that the `_get` method always returns a string the error would fix. How do I do that?

Also _get method won't return a string always. It return what's whats in the path. So the override won't be a global override as well.

Comment: It should be `as string` (lowercase) instead of `as String` -- does that make a difference?

Comment: I looked up this [`TFunctionDetailedResult` type](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/5698af18ce30d6688c1ea354734c2e6279e83bbe/index.d.ts#L795) and it seems like you are getting an `object` rather than a `string`.  You would want to use the `res` property of that object, which is the translated string.  However the translation function will return different types depending on the `returnDetails` and `returnObjects` options.  Are you actually getting a `string`, and it's just a TS error?  Or are you getting an `object`?

Comment: I think `useLocales` is a custom hook?  Possibly your problem is a TS error in that hook.  I'm not sure why you aren't using the `useTranslate` hook from `react-i18next`?  I can fix this if you can create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in codesandbox or typescript playground.

Answer (score 3):

The [`TFunctionDetailedResult` type](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/5698af18ce30d6688c1ea354734c2e6279e83bbe/index.d.ts#L795) is one of the [possible return types](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/5698af18ce30d6688c1ea354734c2e6279e83bbe/index.d.ts#L881) from the `i18next.t` translation function.  `i18next.t` can return a few different types depending on what `options` you provide.  Specifically, the option that we are concerned with here is `returnDetails`.

If you call `t` with `{ returnDetails: true }` in the options then you will get back a result object with type `TFunctionDetailedResult`.

```
export type TFunctionDetailedResult<T = string> = {
  /**
   * The plain used key
   */
  usedKey: string;
  /**
   * The translation result.
   */
  res: T;
  /**
   * The key with context / plural
   */
  exactUsedKey: string;
  /**
   * The used language for this translation.
   */
  usedLng: string;
  /**
   * The used namespace for this translation.
   */
  usedNS: string;
};
```

As you can see, the `.res` property contains the actual result of the translation.  So you can call your snackbar with `result.res` as the message.

You can get back just a `string` if you call `t` with the option `{ returnDetails: false }` or if you don't specify this option at all, as `false` is the default value.

---

In your code, you are expecting a `string` type but getting a `TFunctionDetailedResult` type.  It is unclear to me if this is a TypeScript error, and your result is actually a `string`, or if the TypeScript types are correct and you are getting this results object.

If it is a TypeScript error (your variable is actually a `string` but it is has the type `TFunctionDetailedResult`):

- Make sure that the `translate` function returned from your `useLocales` hook has the type `(...keys: string[]): string`.

If it is an actual error (your variable is a `TFunctionDetailedResult` object):

- You can keep this as an object and use the `.res` property of the object for your snackbar.
- You can modify the options on your `t` call so that you get a `string` result instead.

---

Your issues with the `lodash` `_get` types seem secondary to me.  It did play with this a bit and defined an accurate type for the `error` variable.

```
interface ErrorType {
  response: {
    data: {
      validationFailures: Array<{
        field: string;
        code: string; // or is it a number?
      }>
    }
  }
}
```

Oddly, this gives me the correct type for `_get(error, 'response.data.validationFailures.0')` but not for the next level `_get(error, 'response.data.validationFailures.0.field')`, which I don't understand.  You could do something like this:

```
const { translate } = useLocales();

const failure = _get(error, 'response.data.validationFailures.0');
if (!failure) {
  // do something if you don't have an error message
}
const text = translate(failure.field, failure.code);
```

[Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQYBYw)